# MSYS2 Clang64 Clang++ Linker Problems

Tags: c++, clang++

Currently using clang++ from Clang64 on MSYS2, Windows 10. Compiling with `C:/msys64/clang64/bin/clang++ main.cpp -o main.exe`. When I compile the code below, I get the following error:

`error while loading shared libraries: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

When I comment out the line `std::cout << "Success!\n";`, it compiles and runs without any problems. I've tried using the g++ and clang++ compilers from MingW64 on MSYS2, and they both work without producing any errors. The reason why I'm trying to use this specific compiler is because it can be used with address sanitizer. I would really appreciate any help I can get.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Success!\n";

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: It wants Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2019. It is very strange if the Redistributable is not installed with clang.

Comment: I downloaded Clang64 through this command on the msys2 terminal: `pacman -S mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-clang`. I already had MingW64 installed prior to this. I've added the paths to both bins for Clang64 and MingW64 to my environment variable PATH. I'm very lost on what to do...